# Unity, Vuforia iOs 'App rejected Due to Non-public API'

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

My App - which for some time has been in the App store is now being updated for the forth time. In the meantime Apple wanted me to update to **Xcode 5.1**. How I updated the App was by simply adding some more markers & some more 3d content - I'm using the **Vuforia AR** plugin and Unity iOS pro 3.whatever. Now the App - which runs fine on phone and iPad in iOs 6 and 7 won't upload I get this opaqe message "*App* *rejected Due to Non-public API*"

and

*"The app references non-public symbols in Payload /Myappname.app/Myappname: MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification"*
 ...whatever the hell that is... a search won't find *MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification*

- Anyone know what the fix is?

Comment: Did you find the solution please help me. Same thing is happening with me. I could not find it in search and clueless where might this symbol be used in my project

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) indicates that this method was deprecated in iOS 3.2 and that you should use the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` method to achieve the same function.

Now, if you aren't implementing this method then one of the frameworks you are using must be.  It was deprecated a long time ago, so I would start by updating any external frameworks you are using.